# Horizontal spacing in itemize

Tags: itemize

How can I shift the dots left and right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Horizontal space
\begin{itemize}
    \item Text
    \item Text
    \item Text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `enumitem` package for this. (Negative values for `leftmargin` are acceptable also.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=8em}

\begin{document}
Horizontal space
\begin{itemize}
    \item Text
    \item Text
    \item Text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to do this locally, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Horizontal space
\begin{itemize}[left=8em]
    \item Text
    \item Text
    \item Text
\end{itemize}

Horizontal space
\begin{itemize}[left=-4em]
    \item Text
    \item Text
    \item Text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

which will produce

[image]